# How to set reflected Fields directly to an instance of Object?

Tags: java, reflection, properties

I have a problem setting Fields (java.lang.reflect) from POJO to an instance of the Object class.

The examples I've come across on the internet all use setting those Fields to an instance of a *concrete* class. Since the situation is such that I need a class to have different properties each time, I definitely can't write any classes where I would set those fields. The only logical approach I can think of would be to use an Object class.

To not dive any deeper, what I'm trying is to use this class:

```
class Apple {
    private String color;
    private Double weight;
    private Date order;
    
    //default constructor
    //getters + setters
}
```

and let's say use its field `color` to construct a new class containing **only** that property.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apple apple = someDatabase.findApple();

        Field field = apple.getClass().getDeclaredField("color");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Object value = field.get(apple);

        Object dummy = new Object();
        field.set(dummy, value); //Says: "Cannot set String field to java.lang.Object"
    }
}
```

If this can't be done this way, may someone recommend another solution for this problem?

Comment: The class `Object` does not have a `color` field and even if it had, the `Field` describes the `color` field declared by the `Apple` class and no other. If you want an object mapping arbitrary strings to values, you want a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html). No Reflection needed.

Comment: You probably want a `java.util.HashMap<String,Object>` that holds the "properties".

Answer (score 0):

Just get the constructor via reflection, invoke it, then set the fields.

```
Apple apple = someDatabase.findApple();

Field field = apple.getClass().getDeclaredField("color");
field.setAccessible(true);

Object value = field.get(apple);

Constructor<? extends Apple> appleCtor = apple.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor();
appleCtor.setAccessible(true);

Apple dummy = appleCtor.newInstance();
field.set(dummy, value);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. It takes all the fields from the Apple class and sets them to NULL (except for the `color` field, of course). What I want is to have only 1 field - `color`.

Comment: @StefanJankovic Then what you're asking for does not make sense in the context of Java. An Apple has 3 fields, by definition, and Object has zero.